# simple question: how to pull out some info from an object in Java

Tags: java

I'm working in java, and I have a method that returns a pair, ie. (String, integer). At a different point in the program, I want to pull out the String alone. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `returns a pair` how? is it a Tuple or a KeyValuePair ?

Comment: String someNewString = someObject.SomeMethod().SomeStringValue

Comment: A bit of code to show what you've got / what you want might help...

Comment: A pair ? Can you give us your exact return type ?

Comment: Thx everybody. I got it. It was a brain fart I guess. Still very new to all of this so I am internalizing things on the go. The "someObject.getwhatIwant()" idea just escaped my mind.

Comment: @web_novice118 "simple question: ..".  'What is the meaning of life?' is a simple question.  It is the answer that is tricky.  BTW - How is it you've asked 5 questions with 10 replies and got exactly 0 correct answers?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I cannot register an acct from the computer I use; the network does not allow it. Of course, I would like to. Anyways, I did not now that it was such a big deal to some people.

Comment: @web_novice118 "I cannot register an acct from the computer I use;.."  Given everything I intimated you should do can be done with your existing SO account, I do not see the slightest relevance in wherever else you cannot 'register'. "I did not now that it was such a big deal to some people."  It is only as big a deal as your getting answers.  (So no, it matters not one iota to me.)

Answer (score 0):

add another method returning the `String` only and use that at the mentioned different point in your program

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] method(int param1, int param2){
    //do something
    return new Object[]{"string", 1};
}
....
String value = (String)obj.method(param1, param2)[0];
```

Comment: I think you're missing a cast to String

Answer (score 0):

If you build an object, you can easily get a value from object like getString() (private case) : newString = p1.getString ;

Answer (score 0):

How are you returning a pair?  It might be with an object, or an array.

If it's an object you're returning, it probably looks like this...

```
public ResultObject MyMethod() {
    String s = "foo";
    int i = 42;
    return new ResultObject(s, i);
}

public class ResultObject() {
    public String s;
    public int i;
    public ResultObject(String s, int i) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

And you can access the result like this

```
ResultObject r = MyMethod();
System.out.println(r.s); // "foo"
System.out.println(r.i); // "42"
```

If it's an array you're returning, it probably looks like this...

```
public Object[] MyMethod() {
    String s = "foo";
    int i = 42;
    return new Object[] { s, i };
}
```

And you can access the result like this

```
Object[] r = MyMethod();
System.out.println(r[0]); // "foo"
System.out.println(r[1]); // "42"
```

Returning a result object is preferable, because the array causes you to rely on the order of the results, is less descriptive when you access the result objects (r[0] versus r.somename), is prone to out-of-bounds exceptions, and is not typed (you'll have to cast your result objects to the type they're supposed to be).

Answer (score 0):

For more than a return using a Map  in return.

Para mais de um retorno utilize um Map  como retorno.

```
public Map<String, Integer> method(){
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String s = "foo";
    Integer i = 99;

    map.put(s,i);

    return map;
}
```